# Appearing and disappearing animation with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, transition

I have a checkbox and an image on an HTML page:

I want the image to disappear when the checkbox is checked, and return back when it's unchecked. It can be easily done with the `opacity` property but this will only hide the image – and I need it to disappear (so that other elements can take the image's place for example).
I tried to combine `opacity` with `display` properties:

```css
img {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#checkbox:checked ~ div img {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
    </div>
</body>
```

but it wouldn't work (no transition).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: look it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property

Answer (score 2):

`display` property **cannot be transitioned** nor animated. It works fine without it.

```css
img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#checkbox:checked ~ div img {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
    </div>
</body>
```

You check another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property) for more information.

---

In case you need that space you can animate for example `height` or `max-height`.

```css
img {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 150px;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out, max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#checkbox:checked ~ div img {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: _“It works fine without it”_ - the question was specifically about hiding the element in a way so that it does not take up space any more, and that does _not_ “work fine” with just opacity.

Comment: @CBroe You did not specified explicit request. What would you expect  it to do? Animate opacity and _disappear_ (free space) at the same time is not possible - How it should look like? You might use `height` or `translate` or whatever but _not take up space_ is not animation.

Comment: It’s not my question. _“Animate opacity and disappear (free space) at the same time is not possible”_ - I’m guessing, animate opacity first, disappear after when that is done?